# How to zip a file and split with a max size limit using java

Tags: java, zip

I need to zip a 30MB file into different zip files which have a limit of 5MB per zip file.
My work will stop to zip after the size is larger than the limit now. I referenced and tried some examples but made me feel confused.
Please give me suggestions. Thank you.

```
public static void zipDirectory(File dir, File zipFile, boolean contentOnly)
        throws IOException {
    synchronized (syncObj) {
        FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(zipFile);
        ZipOutputStream zout = new ZipOutputStream(fout);
        if (contentOnly)
            zipSubDirectory("", dir, zout);
        else
            zipSubDirectory(dir.getName() + "/", dir, zout);
        zout.close();
    }
}

private static void zipSubDirectory(String basePath, File dir,
                                              ZipOutputStream zout) throws IOException {

        synchronized (syncObj) {

            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            final long MAX_ZIP_SIZE = 5000000; 
            long currentSize = 0;
            int zipSplitCount = 0;
            ZipEntry zipEntry;
            FileInputStream entryFile;
            File[] files = dir.listFiles();
            for (File file : files) {
                zipEntry = new ZipEntry(basePath + file.getName());
                if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    String path = basePath + file.getName() + "/";
                    zout.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(path));
                    zipSubDirectory(path, file, zout);
                    zout.closeEntry();
                } else {
                    if (currentSize >= MAX_ZIP_SIZE) {
                        zipSplitCount++;
                        zout.close();
                        zout = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file.getName().replace(".zip", ".zip." + zipSplitCount)));
                        currentSize = 0;
                    }
                    zout.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
                    FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(file);
                    int length;
                    while ((length = fin.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                        zout.write(buffer, 0, length);
                    }
                    zout.closeEntry();
                    fin.close();
                }
                currentSize += zipEntry.getCompressedSize();
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: If you want to zip multiple files just start a new zip file when the size is exceeded (you might want to revert the last entry or calculate the size before adding the entry). If you want to zip a "30 MB file" you might need to split that file somehow - if and how this can be done depends on the content of this file (e.g. you couldn't easily split a compressed image).

Comment: You may consider to use Apache Commons Compress which is able to create multivolume ZIP archives. See https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/zip.html